# HttpURLConnection refused in mobile phone but not android emulator

Tags: php, android, post, android-emulator, wampserver

I am currently doing `POST` request from android to PHP WAMP server. I am facing one problem, that is ,it refused to connect with the server (error 403) by using my mobile phone. On the other hand, my android emulator able to connect and perform POST action to PHP server.

```
String urlAddress = "http://192.168.43.133/Test/php_script.php";
HttpURLConnection con=Connector.connect(urlAddress);
int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();
```

In mobile phone debugger mode, I got 403 for the `responseCode`. Anyone faced this kind of problem before?

Comment: are you connected to same network ?

Comment: yup, connected with static ip address

Comment: if you do indeed get a 403, then the packets travel. I am assuming you are running your simulator inside the same box as the server itself, ie they have the same IP addy. Check your Apache settings for virtual hosts to make sure you dont a funky local network condition. Then check also the kind of auth you require in your Apache setup "Allow Override All" and  "Require all granted" in your document root directory. Restart apache and test it.  If that later gets  you working, study all aspects of auth and security for apache, tailor to suit your need.

Answer (score 0):

By default WAMPServer comes configured as a single desktop secure environment, to protect beginners form getting hacked.

So to access it from another device you must tell Apache that that is allowed.

Edit the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. This is where the locahost Virtual Host is defined. Use the WAMPServer menu system.

```
wampmanager-> Apache -> httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Look for this line inside the ` and  tag

```
Require local
```

If you want to allow access from your WiFi network then change it to comething liek this

```
Require ip 192.168.43
```

Note I used only 3 of the 4 quartiles. This says allow any ip address in the `192.168.43` range to connect to this Apache Virtual host

Try and avoid using

```
Require all granted
```

That is a hammer to crack a nut approach and if you ever open up your router would allow anybody in the universe to access your site.

Once you have edited the file and saved it, dont forget to restart Apache

```
wampmanager->Apache-> Service Administration->Restart Apache
```

Answer (score -1):

This is network issue so make sure you have the following checked:

- You firewall
- Both your pc and phone are in the same LAN
- Check if you can access your server from another device on the network

Comment: 1. I have already turned off my Windows Firewall.

2. Pc and phone are in the same ip address

3. I can perform POST through POSTMAN

Comment: Postman and Local emulator are running on the same PC as your WAMP server so its not going over the network. When you try your app from real device it needs to connect to the server over your LAN (or public network interface which requires some additional steps)

Comment: Also check your backend implementation, error 403 means your server is fine, but there is something funky going on with the authentication flow

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, WAMP by defdault only accept conections coming from the same computer, so trying to access it from another device even though on the same network won't work, for that you need to first disable any firewall installed on your computer then go to windows firewall and add WAMP as an exception, and then try, if it doesn't work, then google how to allow connection from external devices to WAMP

Comment: `for that you need to first disable any firewall installed on your computer `. That is nonsense. You said that wamp did not accept other connections. And i believe that that is true. So it has nothing to do with the firewall if wamp prevents it. And if wamp prevents it you have to change the configuration of wamp.

Comment: Yeah, but i actually had this issue twice, once long ago, a year ago i believe, and it had nothing to do with the firewall, the fix was to configure WAMP to accept external connections, the second time was a week ago with the newest version of WAMP and Win10, and it turned that my WAMP installed already configured to accept external connection, however Windows 10 Firewall was blocking it, so the fix was to add WAMP as an exception.